# CountDownLatch - understanding await and countDown

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

According to Javadoc:
A CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. The await methods block until the current count reaches zero.

That means in the below code, since I initialized the CountDownLatch to 1. All threads should get unblocked from its await method as soon as the latch calls countdown.

But, the main thread is waiting for all the threads to complete. And also, I didn't join the main thread to end of the other threads. Why is the main thread waiting?

```
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Sample implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public Sample(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    private static AtomicLong number = new AtomicLong(0);

    public long next() {
         return number.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        for (int threadNo = 0; threadNo < 4000; threadNo++) {
          Runnable t = new Sample(latch);
          new Thread(t).start();
        }
        try {
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println("Count:"+next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running the following modified version of your code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    public Test(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }
    private static AtomicLong number = new AtomicLong(0);

    public long next() {
         return number.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        for (int threadNo = 0; threadNo < 1000; threadNo++) {
          Runnable t = new Test(latch);
          new Thread(t).start();
        }
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "done" );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 + (int) ( Math.random() * 3000 ));
            System.out.println(next());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }

}
```

You should see something like:

> 0
>  done
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  5
>  6
>  7
>  8
>  9
>   10
>  11
>  12
>  13
>  14
>  15
>  16
>  17
>  18
>  19

This indicates that the main thread did, in fact, unblock from the `latch.await()` call after the first thread called `latch.countDown()`

Answer (score 1):

you are starting 4000 threads and they are only waiting 100 milliseconds.  you are most likely overwhelming the box (and all threads will be ending at roughly the same time).  add a sleep in your thread start look and try increasing the timeout to see it work as your expect.

Comment: I added some randomness to the sleep call:

`Thread.sleep(1000 + (int) ( Math.random() * 3000 ));`

and a print statement after `latch.await()` and things worked as expected

Comment: I have changed implementation, can you please respond why is it behaving like this? Why is the main Thread waiting for all threads to complete? I didn't put any join asking the main thread to wait until all the threads complete.

Comment: While using Countdown latch, we need to consider two things -
1.you are blocking N threads/tasks at one line of code, thread.await
2.you must have a criteria of waking each thread which awaits and remember the waking up can be done by some another thread since rest of them are awaiting!

Answer (score 0):

Here is good example for reference. No matter how long dependent threads takes to get ready ( by calling await()), main thread will pause and wait for them to be ready.

```
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CountDownLatchDemo {
    @SneakyThrows
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountDownLatch cl = new CountDownLatch(4);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        DependentService ds1 = new DependentService(cl, "DependenService 1");
        DependentService ds2 = new DependentService(cl, "DependenService 2");
        DependentService ds3 = new DependentService(cl, "DependenService 3");
        DependentService ds4 = new DependentService(cl, "DependenService 4");
        es.submit(ds1);
        es.submit(ds2);
        es.submit(ds3);
        es.submit(ds4);
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 100));
        System.out.println("Main Thread ready");
        es.shutdownNow();
    }


    private static class DependentService implements Runnable {
        private final String name;
        private final CountDownLatch cl;

        public DependentService(CountDownLatch cl, String name) {
            this.cl = cl;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(name + "working");
            cl.await();
            System.out.println(name + " Initialised!");
        }
    }
}
```

In output "Main Thread is ready" will always be last line.

```
DependenService 2working
DependenService 4working
DependenService 1working
DependenService 3working
Main Thread ready
```

---